# Access page from Symfony 6 bundle - get route and twig in custom bundle

Tags: symfony6

I created a bundle,
I want to create a route through the controller in the bundle and present it to the user with the twig file from the bundle.

Symfony is running my bundle successfully.
I am loading services.yaml and routes.yaml in the extension.

Error:
There is no extension able to load the configuration for "bundle_test" (in "*hiddenpath*\vendor\bundle-test\src\DependencyInjection/../Resources/config\routes.yaml"). Looked for namespace "bundle_test", found "none".

There is a point I missed and the documents don't tell me anything.

files:
bundle file:
src/BundleTestBundle
config files:

Resources/config/routes.yaml:
 `bundle_test: resource: "@BundleTestBundle/Controller/" type: annotation`

Resources/config/services.yaml
...
Extension & Configuration file:
src/DependencyInjection/BundleTestExtension.php (extends Extension)
src/DependencyInjection/Configuration.php

Controller:
src/Controller/TestController.php (extends AbstractController)

Servisleri okumayı ve yaml ve xml ile yapılandırmayı denedim.
Yapılandırma ve uzantı dosyalarıyla çok uğraştım.

istediğim şey bundle ile oluşturulmuş bir controller ve bundle üzerindeki bir twig'in çalışması

ex:
http://.........../routeInBundle
--> vendor/testbundle/../test_bundle.html.twig

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.